# Is there a word that can be used to mean 'wear' in general?

Tags: vocabulary

There are a number of words that mean 'wear' in certain situations - for example, 쓰다, 메다, 신다, 매다, and so on.

> 왜 선글라스를 쓰고있어? Why are you wearing sunglasses?
>
> 초등학생들은 어깨에 가방을 메고 가요. Elementary students wear their school bags over
>   their shoulders.
>
> 방 안에 신발 신지마라! Don't wear your shoes in the house!
>
> 스카프를 매고있어요 I'm wearing a scarf.

These examples from [koreanselfstudyisntlame](http://koreanselfstudyisntlame.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/kgysak-many-verbs-of-to-wear-etc.html).

However, I have also seen 하다 used to mean 'wear':

> 귀 덥개를 하다 – wear earmuffs

And of course there is 입다 which also means 'wear'.

So my question is : can either 입다 or 하다 be used correctly with any item of clothing (or accessory)? If not, is there a word that can?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first Korean word that immediately comes to mind is '[착용(着用)하다](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=36659101)' which means:

> 동사 (verb)
>
> 「…을」 의복 (clothes), 모자 (cap or hat), 신발 (footwear) 따위 (etc.)를 입거나 (wear), 쓰거나 (put on), 신거나 (wear) 하다.
>
> 구명조끼를 착용하다 Subject wears a life jacket.
>
> 수영모를 착용하다 Subject wears a swimming cap.
>
> 전 장병은 전투복을 착용하도록 지시되었다. All solders were ordered to wear a battle uniform.

1. '쓰다' is used for 안경 (glasses), 모자 (cap or hat), 우산 (umbrella) and 마스크 (mask), etc. that are usually used to cover a part or all of your head. You wear a 스키 마스크 (ski mask) and '쓰다' should be for it.
2. '메다' is close to to carry (on your shoulder). That's why you use '메다' for your school bag which is carried over your shoulder.
3. '신다' is to wear things to cover your feet, e.g., 양말 (socks), 신발 (shoes), 슬리퍼 (slipper), 부츠 (boots), 운동화 (sneakers), 전투화 (combat or military boots), etc.
4. '입다' is used for all the other things especially covering a part or all of your body such as 옷 (clothes), 팬티 (panties, underwear), 군복 (military uniform), 치마 (skirt), 바지 (trousers), 브라자 (bra / brassiere) and 드레스 (dress), etc.
5. '매다' is used for a relatively thin items such as 허리띠 (belt), 넥타이 (necktie), 안전띠 (seat belt) and 스카프 (scarf), etc..
6. '하다' is used for small items covering only a small part of your body such as 귀덥개 (earmuffs), 마스크 (mask) and 안대 (eye patch), etc.
7. Sometimes you use '차다' for relatively small items such as 기저귀 (diaper), 브라 (bra / brassiere), 손목시계 (wrist watch), etc.

> 왜 선글라스를 착용하고 있어? Why are you wearing sunglasses?
>
> 초등학생들은 어깨에 가방을 착용하고 가요. Elementary students wear their school bags
> over their shoulders.
>
> 방 안에 신발 착용하지 마라! Don't wear your shoes in the house!
>
> 스카프를 착용하고 있어요 I'm wearing a scarf.

All of the above sentences make sense, but sound a little awkward and unnatural because there is no reason to use '착용하다' in the sentences. You use '착용하다' in official documents or for a warning or sign as follows:

> 실내에서 신발 (선글라스) 착용 금지. No outdoor footwear (sunglasses) is allowed
> indoor.